# Volley JSONObjectRequest and JSONArrayRequest both are giving errors Android Java

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am trying to parse a JSON data as follows:

```
{"Returnresult":[{"api_status":"1","user_temp_id":"280","otp":"1234"}]}
```

I followed the tutorial given on Android Developer website and tried

```
  String url = "some url";

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest;
    jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            response -> {

                String api_status = null;
                try {
                    JSONArray obj = response.getJSONArray(0);
                    api_status = obj.getString(0);
                    System.out.println(" api_status is" + api_status);
               
                      if (api_status.equals("1")) {
                      //some code
                      }
```

I am getting stuck at

```
JSONArray obj = response.getJSONArray(0); // Tried as array this time
```

1. If I try to get it as JSONArray, it error shows that "....of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray", when I try:

   JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(0);
2. If I try to get it as JSONObject, it error shows that "....of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject", with JSONObjectRequest on top

Please help !

Edited code as per Dharmender:

```
  RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(trial1.this);

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                response ->  {
                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                       try {
                           JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                           JSONArray returnresult = json.getJSONArray("Returnresult");

                           for(int countItem = 0;countItem<returnresult.length();countItem++){
                               JSONObject returnObject = returnresult.getJSONObject(countItem);
                               String apiStatus=returnObject.isNull("api_status")?"":returnObject.optString("api_status");
                               System.out.println("Status is "+apiStatus);
                           }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with following code.

```
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(trial1.this);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            response ->  {
                System.out.println(response.toString());
                   try {
                       JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                       JSONArray returnresult = json.getJSONArray("Returnresult");

                       for(int countItem = 0;countItem<returnresult.length();countItem++){
                           JSONObject returnObject = returnresult.getJSONObject(countItem);
                           String apiStatus=returnObject.isNull("api_status")?"":returnObject.optString("api_status");
                           System.out.println("Status is "+apiStatus);
                       }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
```

Comment: I am getting Cannot resolve constructor 'JSONObject(org.json.JSONArray)' when creating json (1st line)

Comment: try again i have update the code, add passing response object as a String

Comment: Hey Dharmender, thanks for helping me out. Its not showing error but also not doing anything else. I tried printing the String, but nothing happened. The full code is above in edit.

Comment: can you tell me what is data type of response object

Comment: Its lambda for new Response<JSONArray>

Comment: i have update code with this  line now it should work. JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest